# Diaz Canel Singao

Tags: css, django, bootstrap-4

I have these problem, I need to generate a col-md-4 from Django-Admin, the trouble is that I want to show other col-md-4 just if the previous col-md-4 get 10 items.

Please help me, is my tesis

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="single-price" style="border-radius: 8px;">
                    <ul class="price-list">
                        {% for doc in Documento %}
                        {% if 10 >= forloop.counter %}

                        <li class="d-flex align-items-center"><a href="{{ doc.documento.url }}" download=""
                                target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                                <img src="{{ doc.ícono.url }}" alt="" style="width: 40px; margin-right: 10px;"> </a>
                            <span style="text-align: left;">{{ doc.nombre }}</span>
                            <!-- <a href="/static/descargables/Ctto-Marco-MAR-2022-.docx" download="true"
                                    class="price-btn">Descargar</a> -->
                        </li>
                        {% endif %}


                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```